# Nhibernate 3.0:Mapping in the hbm.xml file for a relational table step by step procedure needed

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I'm using an Nhibernate version 3.0 and this is my first time im using it.I would like to know how can i create an hbm.xml file for the tables where relationship exists between them.  Here is my scenario i have two tables named table A and table B. Table B primary key is the foriegn key in the table A. for this how i need to write the hbm file and also how i need to insert the values into both the tables simultaneously by using only one object. (ie., how should i need to write the table A class file and table B class file.)

if any one explains me in the set by step procedure it will be easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the NH doc. The relationship you are talking is a `<many-to-one/>`, search for it here:

http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping/1nr4enxv3dpeq/8#

you will find some examples. In order to have the intellisense inside Visual Studio when you write the HBM files, you can copy these files

```
nhibernate-configuration.xsd
nhibernate-mapping.xsd
```

in the `C:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio xxx\Xml\Schemas` path.

In order to save simultaneously the referred entity you have to ensure to apply `cascade="save-update"` on the `<many-to-one/>` tag.